# SQL join related question

Tags: sql, join

I am having trouble with a SQL join question.

I have a table `EMPLOYEE` with `EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone`

I have another table `OTHERNAME` with 2 fields `"Name" & "OtherName"`.

This table contains lookup values such as `"James", "Jim"; "Thomas", "Tom"; "Steven", "Steve"`.

I want to write a query which will return rows

```
EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, OtherName
where Employee.Firstname = OTHERName.Name
```

Comment: Do you call everyone by their alternative names. What about people called Richard..? Should the alternative name really be tied to the actual employee ID instead of first name.

Comment: No because OTHERNAME only has "lookup" type data. This means the OTHERNAME will only have one record for ROBERT, BOB; or one record for THOMAS,TOM;
regardless if there are 12 Roberts in the company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select e.EmpID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Email, e.Phone, o.OtherName
From Employee e
Left Outer Join OtherName o on e.FirstName = o.Name
```

From your comments it sounds like you actually want an outer join.

(From Comments) An outer join would return all employees, along with an Othername if there is one, otherwise Othername would be a null value which you could handle in code. An inner join limits the results to only employees with a matching record.

Comment: Then the original query should do the job.

Comment: well, I want to return ALL rows from Employee. If there is a match found in OTHERName, then retrun that value

Comment: Well then that would be an outer join. An outer join would return all employees, along with an Othername if there is one, otherwise Othername would be a null value which you could handle in code. An inner join limits the results to only employees with a matching record.

Comment: No problem, but if the question has been resolved, please remember to Mark as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT
    e.EmpID
        CASE 
            WHEN o.OtherName IS NOT NULL THEN OtherName
            ELSE e.FirstName
        END AS FirstName
        ,e.LastName
        ,e.Email
        ,e.Phone
        ,o.OtherName
    FROM Employee             e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OtherName o ON e.FirstName = o.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.EmpID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Email, e.Phone, o.OtherName 
from employee e,othername o 
where e.FirstName=o.name
```

Comment: you should use explicit JOIN syntax and not join tables with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.EmpID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Email, E.Phone, O.OtherName
FROM Employee E 
    INNER JOIN Othername O
        ON E.Firstname = O.Name
```

Should do the trick

Or, if you want all results, even those without "other name" values.

```
SELECT E.EmpID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Email, E.Phone, O.OtherName
FROM Employee E 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Othername O
        ON E.Firstname = O.Name
```

Comment: That will filter out all employee who do not have any "other name" - not what the OP wanted, I presume....

Comment: Based on the posters comments, he is looking for an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT E.EmpId, 
E.FirstName, 
E.LastName, 
E.Email, 
E.Phone, 
O.OtherName
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN OTHERNAME O
ON E.FirstName = O.Name

Comment: That will filter out all employee who do not have any "other name" - not what the OP wanted, I presume....

Answer (score 0):

You may use following SQL Command

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.EmpID, 
       EMPLOYEE.FirstName, 
       EMPLOYEE.LastName, 
       EMPLOYEE.Email, 
       EMPLOYEE.Phone, 
       OTHERNAME.OtherName FROM EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN OTHERNAME ON EMPLOYEE.FirstName = OTHERNAME.Name
```